# Merge part of a branch into master with git

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, dvcs

I'll explain my scenario:

1. I have two git branches say `master`, `branch1`
2. My `master` branch has following files and commits associated with it - it's like after each file i created i did `git commit`:

   ```
   master-file1.html has masterfile1-commit-message
   master-file2.html - masterfile2-commit-message
   master-file3.html - masterfile3-commit-message
   ```
3. My `branch1` branch has following files and commits associated with it:

   ```
   branch1-file1.html has branch1file1-commit-message
   branch1-file2.html - branch1file2-commit-message
   branch1-file3.html - branch1file3-commit-message
   branch1-file4.html - branch1file4-commit-message
   branch1-file5.html - branch1file5-commit-message
   ```

So i don't want to merge `branch1` completely to `master` branch, i just want partial merge. So at the final i want is something like this:

1. My `master` branch should be like this:

   ```
   master-file1.html has masterfile1-commit-message
   master-file2.html - masterfile2-commit-message
   master-file3.html - masterfile3-commit-message
   branch1-file1.html has branch1file1-commit-message
   branch1-file2.html - branch1file2-commit-message
   ```
2. My `branch1` branch should be unchanged:

   ```
   branch1-file1.html has branch1file1-commit-message
   branch1-file2.html - branch1file2-commit-message
   branch1-file3.html - branch1file3-commit-message
   branch1-file4.html - branch1file4-commit-message
   branch1-file5.html - branch1file5-commit-message
   ```

Can i achieve this in git? If so then how?

Comment: Look for cherrypick

Comment: @MrTux A merge would be better. See my answer for details.

Comment: Does `branch1` also have the the master files?

Comment: @MrTux What is cherrypick?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Yes, i forgot to add that!

Comment: MrTux is referring to `git cherry-pick` which can be useful for copying a commit from one branch to anther. I don't think it will help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the SHA1 hash for the commit with `branch1-file2.html`. You can do this with the following commands:

```
git checkout branch1
git log --oneline
```

Look for the hex string at the beginning of each line. Now once you have the hash, just merge `master` to it:

```
git checkout master
git merge <SHA1 hash>
```

Comment: Then can i go back to original? i.e. Master branch as it is?

Comment: @AdityaNagla This will change the master branch to point at the commit that you merge to. However, you can always check out any commit you wish with its SHA1 hash, including the commit where your `master` was originally.

Comment: @AdityaNagla I suggest you read a bit more about commits and branches. [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a book which is freely available online. The first 3 chapters contain 90% of what you need for day-to-day use.